# How to show rest of text after click with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Good day,

I created a code in jQuery, where is displayed just first word and after click is shown rest of this text. But there I have a 'blinking efect' when this text is showing. Do you know how to correct it? Thank you.

Code

```
var clicks = 0;
$('#block').click(function(){
    if(clicks === 0){
        $("#block").animate({width: "300px"});
        $("#b_1_more").show();
        clicks++;
    }else{
        $("#block").animate({width: "50px"});
        $("#b_1_more").hide();
        clicks = 0;
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zA23k/1573/)

Comment: The moment you click, the full text is already being displayed but the area it is in at that time is still too small for one line. That's why you're seeing the 'blinking' effect which is actually your element temporarily extending the text to the second line.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mnLth3gj/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though `$("#b_1_more").show()` is executed after `$("#block").animate(...);` the hidden text is shown before the animation completes.

If you show the extended text **after** the animation is finished, there will be no blinking:

```
$("#block").animate({width: "300px"}, function() {
   $("#b_1_more").show();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L7dq3zbv/1/

Another possible solution is to tell the `#block` element not to blink using css:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kzezobgj/1/

Answer (score 0):

This could be shortened also, You don't even need to counter with the variable.

use `.toggleClass()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#block').click(function(){
        $('#block').toggleClass('toggleWidth linear')
        $("#b_1_more").toggle();
    });
});
```

May be not exact animation but can help.

Demo- http://jsfiddle.net/4je6j9h8/